# Python opening a hebrew path to file and using glob with hebrew

Tags: python, unicode, hebrew

I have a root dir in hebrew and a file name in hebrew.
I wish to do the following:

```
fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, fileName)
f = file(fullPath)
```

and also I wish to find all the excel files that starts with a hebrew prefix:

```
excelPath= os.path.join(dirName, "%s*.xlsx" % hebrewPrefix)
for fn in glob.glob(excelPath):
            print fn
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x? How did your code failed? Can't speak for Hebrew, but for French this works as expected on Python 2.6 -- both using plain strings and "unicode" stings.

Comment: With python 2 or 3? In Python 2, and with file names encoded in UTF-8 (default on modern Linux), the code should already work as written.

Comment: On Windows you will have difficulty accessing files with names outside the system default code page unless you use Unicode strings for pathnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected on Japanese (assuming I have the folder *こんにちは* containing the file *世界.xls*):

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> fullpath = os.path.join("こんにちは","世界.*")
>>> import glob
>>> for fn in glob.glob(fullpath):
...     print fn
... 
こんにちは/世界.xls
```

You shouldn't have any difficulties in Hebrew. The only problem would be if your filesystem does not support UTF-8 for file names...